How do you say "Mary as Queen of the Rosary"?
This is for a piece of artwork that depicts Mary and her child in the middle with three wreaths of rose petals. The Heart of Mary and the Heart of Jesus appear in the rose petal wreaths next to her. The three rose circles, each with 50 small and 5 large roses, symbolize the rosary prayer, which consists of 150 Hail Marys and 15 Our Fathers.

I'm assuming you want an Ecclesiastical Latin translation, given the context? (For a phrase this short, it doesn't really make a difference, but for longer texts the grammar can vary a lot.)

Since you seem to be running a business producing this art I feel you should probably be paying a translator for these questions rather than getting free labour online.

@Cairnarvon We all do free labor for StackExchange. I'm happy to do a little free labor for someone who wants to put Latin on a nice product.

If you just want a title to put onto or into a painting or other visual depiction, you can write:

Maria Regina Rosarii

This drops the "as" from the English.

Thank you, Ben!
